# Control flow rate of a solenoid valve using PWM

Tags: pwm, solenoid, solenoid-valve, flow-control

I'm hoping to control the flow of chemical by shutting a solenoid valve periodically over short intervals, similar to this video: https://youtu.be/O49mqn33vBI?t=6

Does anyone know if conventional solenoids can be controlled by PWM to produce, say, 500 cycles per minute? Is banging a 'conventional' solenoid that rapidly a good idea usually? By conventional solenoids, I mean those found in coffee machines and others commonly available:

[image]

If not, how are PWM solenoids constructed differently?

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: It's product dependent and not general so contact a solenoid/valve supplier.

Comment: See if [proportional-valves](https://www.machinedesign.com/mechanical-motion-systems/hydraulics/article/21812909/proportional-valves) helps your understanding.

Comment: @Transistor I've looked into them but they cost way too much for me (upward of $200 each?).

Comment: As an example, a GM automotive EGR valve uses 3 solenoid coils that pass airflow at rates of 1, 2, and 4. Digital switching activates these coils in combination to achieve 8 distinct flow rates including zero. The 3 coils operate a single tapered pintle valve.

Comment: Most components with moving parts should include a “lifetime” rating in cycles. A 1,000,000 cycle rated solenoid valve at 500 cycles/minute gives 2000 minutes as the rated usage time. Is that enough to make your design practical ?

Comment: Also check the operating speed of the solenoid.